# admob on android studio not working

Tags: java, android, xml, admob, show

I input the codes below and test it by connecting it with my phone and enabling USB debugging, also I generate a signed apk of it and still not working, please help me, I'm just new in android studio and in writing android applications.

at string.xml that is not my real ad unit id, i censored some numbers

MainActivity.java

```
    package funaisraeljumbo.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem; 
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;



public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
public void onClick(View v){

    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.button3:
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), BasicDifferentiation.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    }

}


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

         //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
         if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
              return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adView">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/rules_for_differentiation"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:onClick="onClick" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/trigonometric_function"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:onClick="onClick" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/log_and_expo"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>


</LinearLayout>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/home">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</LinearLayout>
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "funaisraeljumbo.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     '    proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.8.0'
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="funaisraeljumbo.myapplication" >


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".BasicDifferentiation"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_basic_differentiation" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
                     android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

string.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Differential Calculus Formula (Beta)</string>

    <string name="hello_world">Differential Calculus Formula</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="rules_for_differentiation">Rules For Differentiation</string>
    <string name="trigonometric_function">Differentiation of Trigonometric Function</string>
    <string name="log_and_expo">Differentiation of Logarithmic and Exponential Function</string>
    <string name="title_activity_basic_differentiation">Basic Differentiation</string>
    <string name="home">ca-app-pub-1x104x92x9x2x52x/272xx4x6x2</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Please used ad id - ca-app-pub-1x104x92x9x2x52x

Comment: my string id for that ad id is "home" on strings.xml and i used that string on activity_main.xml

Comment: when i look at the design tab on activity_main.xml i can see a white banner with "ads by google", but when i test it no banner is appearing

Comment: <string name="home">ca-app-pub-1x104x92x9x2x52x</string> dont use string forward slash & string after it. It will work if you did everything perfectly.

Comment: still not showing banner ads when i test it, bro. there no errors showing up from the beginning

Answer (score 0):

Open SDK manager and install google play service.

then add this line to the Gradle (Module)

```
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
```